# Нужны ли кавычки на вывеске?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

Над дорогой они увидели вывеску, где было написано "Сиротский приют"? Нужны ли кавычки в данном предложении?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Несомненно нужны. Это условное название благотворительного заведения.

[Как правильно употреблять кавычки в собственных наименованиях](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/75-kav2)

На самой вывеске никаких кавычек, конечно, не будет, но мы как бы цитируем вывеску, вводя в предложение слова "было написано", "было начертано", "значилось" и т. д.

Comment: спасибо вам за ответ...